# Le remplacement de « w » par « g »

Tags: étymologie, orthographe, histoire, linguistique, ancien-français

Il y a beaucoup de mots qui sont issus d’un mot francique. Voici quatre mots franciques avec les mots français d’aujourd’hui à côté.

- werra, guerre
- witan, guider
- want, gant
- waskon, gâcher

Je trouve ça surprenant que le « w » soit souvent remplacé par un « g » tandis que le « v » ressemble plus au « w ». Pouvez-vous me dire pourquoi ce changement a eu lieu ?

Comment: Il y a ce même glissement avec William/Guillaume.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

À l'époque, le français avait encore la combinaison de sons /gw/ héritée du latin, mais pas le /w/ seul en début de mot (d'ailleurs il demeure rare en français, seulement dans les noms d'origine étrangère, d'où la prononciation /v/ dans *wagon* car /gw/ avait pratiquement disparu de la langue et n'était plus senti comme proche de cette consonne étrangère), et cette combinaison de sons, par la suite réduite à /g/ seul, était ce qui se rapprochait le plus du son étranger.

Comment: Le w fransique devait être particulièrement dur, peut-être même accompagné d'une aspiration, au point qu'on a inventé une règle d'orthographe (le g devant une voyelle se prononce j, sauf gu qui se prononce g). L'assimilation du w au v (qui est probalement contemporaine de l'assimilation du g au j) est récente et n'est pas encore réalisée en Belgique, plus proche du Flammand.